# Прочитать конкретную строчку файла C#

Tags: c#

Есть txt файл со следующим содержанием:

```
1) бла бла 
2) бла бла бла 
3) бла бла бла бла
```

Мне нужно записать в переменную не весь файл, а только вторую строку. Как это сделать?

PS: сори за потенциально тупой вопрос, но это важно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string secondLine = File.ReadLines("MyTextFile.txt").ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

Comment: Только бы в using обернуть

Comment: @Андрей, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379323/7099288

Comment: @AresGod when it encounters an EOF, or if a fault occurs - т.е. в случае > 2 строк в файле будет висеть открытым до финализации

Answer (score 6):

```
string secondLine;
using(var reader = new StreamReader("MyTextFile.txt"))
{
    reader.ReadLine(); // чтобы пропустить одну строку
    secondLine = reader.ReadLine();  // записываем в переменную
}
```